# SAS: choosing the right model

Tags: sas

I'm getting a bit lost in alle the possible ways to find association...
I have a dataset in which my subjects are categorized 1, 2 or 3 (depending on genotype polymorphisms). I want to know the association of either polymorphism with ballistic strength (which is a continuous variable).

Since I have one continous independent variable (strength) and one categorical dependant variable (genotype pholymorphism), I taught of using ANOVA, but I'm not sure which test to choose and how to find the exact one in SAS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is better asked on Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

That said, I would look at PROC GENMOD or PROC GLM to get an idea of how the genotypes affect the strength variable.

```
proc genmod data=test;
class genotype ;
model strength = genotype / type1;
run;
```

You can use PROC TTEST to compare any two levels.  Here I compare A to B.

```
proc ttest data=test(where=(genotype in ('A', 'B')));
class genotype;
var strength;
run;
```

Comment: If it belongs on a different forum you should vote to close as off topic with the new forum as a suggestion :)

Comment: Yeah, I try not to be **THAT GUY**.  I'll provide a basic answer and point you to a place to get a more indepth discussion.